# Worker Service looking for appsettings.json in System32 folder instead of local folder

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-services, appsettings, worker-process

I have a .Net core worker service, which I am running as a windows service. The service is using appsettings.json file for the config information. After installing the service using `SC CREATE` command, the service was failing.

In the event viewer I found the error it cannot find the file `C:\Windows\System32\appsettings.json`. My service files are placed in a different folder `c:\Services\`, instead of looking at that location, the service is looking for a the file in System32 folder.

The configuration registration is as below.

```
 var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
var configuration = configBuilder.Build();
            services.AddSingleton(configuration);
```

How can I make the service to look at the local folder?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue @ajith?

Comment: @MaxMedina I managed to solve it bit the one marked as Answer. I used Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because the current directory is changed to `C:\Windows\System32` at runtime. You could get a relative path by `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`. For example:

```cs
var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath( Path.GetDirectoryName( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
var configuration = configBuilder.Build();
```

Comment: I tried this. Got error
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: C:\Services\MyAssemblyName.dll\

Comment: @Ajith Did you use `Path.GetDirectoryName( )` as I did above? or use exactly the same code as mine? I test my above code. It works fine for me.

Comment: @itminus I have used the same as your code. But still getting the same error on EventViewer.Do you know other possible reason for this issue?

Comment: @ShaileeShah used the solution suggested by itminus above. It is using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location

Comment: It didn't work for me either, but pointed me in the Event Log that the assembly is running from `'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\.net\<AssemblyName>\<weirdalphanum>`. Which goes against what's in the docs from MS.

Answer (score 6):

I´ve successfully used the docs in [Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#app-configuration)

In a nutshell, you should just add `.UseWindowsService()` in your configuration builder step, like in the following:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configuration) => 
        {
            //...set your configurations here
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            //...configure you services here
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it differently by setting the ContentRoot. But I'm installing the service to windows using Wix.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ConverterService
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
            string pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);

            CreateHostBuilder(args, pathToContentRoot).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args, string contentRoot) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .UseContentRoot(contentRoot)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    ConverterConfig config = hostContext.Configuration
                    .GetSection("ConverterConfig")
                    .Get<ConverterConfig>();

                    config.RootPath = contentRoot;

                    services.AddSingleton(config);
                    services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` (as suggested in other answers) returned an empty string when called from a .Net 8 Windows service. `AppContext.BaseDirectory` is what worked for me. [source](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/5467#issuecomment-369202524)

The code in the question would need to change to:

```
var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
```

Comment: This worked for me and the .net8 v8.0.0.  Thank you!